# Как решить проблему "wsl : Имя "wsl" не распознано как имя командлета..."?

Tags: windows, wsl, wsl2

Ввожу "wsl --install"
Появляется следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подозреваю, что тот, кто ставил винду, ставил минимальную сборку "без мусора". Концы сейчас не найти, а wsl2 нужен.

Подскажите, как установить **wsl 2**?

- Выпуск    Windows 11 Pro
- Версия    21H2
- Дата установки    ‎02.‎12.‎2022
- Сборка ОС 22000.318
- Взаимодействие    Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.318.0

Спасибо!

---

UPD

В списке компонентов Windows WSL я не нашел
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Панель управления\Все элементы панели управления\Программы и компоненты\Включение отключение компонентов Windows

Comment: @user7860670 см **UPD**

Comment: https://i0.wp.com/pureinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/virtual-machine-platform-enable-widnows-11.jpg?w=415&quality=78&strip=all&ssl=1

Comment: @user7860670, у меня нет этого пункта(